# How to create something like a sniffer?

Tags: c++, usb

I want to create an app to monitor and save the received data (for test my program!).
The device I'm working with have an API itself, and I want to create an app to get data from the device using CyPress CyAPI (FX3). For that the device should open and start streaming data.
My code is something like this for now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <future>

#include <DeviceAPI.h>
#include <WrapperCyAPI.h>

int main()
{
  std::promise<void> prm;
  std::future<void> fut{ prm.get_future() };
  std::thread th1{
    [&prm]()
    {
      Device device;
      device.open();
      device.init(); // init and open send/receive some data, so I don't want to get them
      prm.set_value();
      device.getData();
      
      device.close();
    }
  };


  std::thread th2{
    [&fut]()
    {
      WrapperCyAPI usb;
      usb.open();
      usb.init();
      fut.wait();
      std::vector<uint8_t> data{ usb.getData() };
      usb.close();
    }
  };

  th1.join();
  th2.join();
}
```

So far so good. The `device.open()` and `device.init()` send configure parameters and receive some information and when I call `device.getData()`, the device sends data and I want to get that data. lets say it sends 100KB data in one endpoint, then in `th2` I use `WrapperCyAPI` which is a wrapper of [CyAPI](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/34631/CyAPI.pdf). `usb.open()` and `usb.init()` just open the device with a handler and then with `usb.getData()` I just received the data.
All of this works just fine, BUT when we have only one endpoint!

In the `usb.getData()`:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> USB::getData()
{
  long receivedSize{ static_cast<long>(buffer.size()) };
  device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN)->XferData(&buffer[0], receivedSize);
  return { buffer }; // imagine buffer2 is empty, a dummy vector reserved for future
}
```

There is no problem. Device sends the data and I get all of them.

But when I want to get data from two endpoint (device sends the data to 2 endpoints too, lets say two 100KB in two endpoints, total data size will be 200KB) I get the error on `XferData` function.

```
// ...

int main()
{
  // ...
  std::thread th2{
    [&fut]()
    {
      WrapperCyAPI usb;
      usb.open();
      usb.init();
      fut.wait();
      std::tuple<std::vector<uint8_t>, std::vector<uint8_t>> data{ usb.getData() };
      usb.close();
    }
  };
// ...
}

// ...

std::tuple<std::vector<uint8_t>, std::vector<uint8_t>> USB:getData()
{
  long receivedSize{ static_cast<long>(buffer1.size()) };
  device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN1)->XferData(&buffer1[0], receivedSize);
  receivedSize = static_cast<long>(buffer2.size());
  device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN2)->XferData(&buffer2[0], receivedSize);
  return { buffer1, buffer2 };
}
```

For second endpoint `XferData` return false. Which means I get half of data (100KB) in the first endpoint, and for the second endpoint `XferData` return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometimes, figuring out that I should read two endpoint asynchronously not synchronously.

```
std::tuple<std::vector<uint8_t>, std::vector<uint8_t>> USB::getData()
{
  OVERLAPPED ov1, ov2;
  ov1.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, L"CYUSB_IN");
  ov2.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, L"CYUSB_IN");

  UCHAR* inCtx1{ device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN1)->BeginDataXfer(&buffer1[0], buffer1.size(), &ov1) };
  UCHAR* inCtx2{ device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN2)->BeginDataXfer(&buffer2[0], buffer2.size(), &ov2) };

  device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN1)->WaitForXfer(&ov1, 3000);
  device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN2)->WaitForXfer(&ov2, 3000);

  long buffer1Size{ static_cast<long>(buffer1.size()) },
       buffer2Size{ static_cast<long>(buffer2.size()) };
  device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN1)->FinishDataXfer(&buffer1[0], buffer1Size, &ov1, inCtx1);
  device->EndPointOf(ENDPOINT_IN2)->FinishDataXfer(&buffer2[0], buffer2Size, &ov2, inCtx2);

  return { buffer1, buffer2 };
}
```